# SQS messages remain in flight though it has been processed by lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

SQS messages get processed successfully by lambda. Here is the code that processes and then executes the callback:

```
 exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
   handleSQSMessages(context,event, function () {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'SQS event processed.',
            input: event,
        }),
    };
    console.log ("OK DONE");
    callback(null, response);

function handleSQSMessages(context, messages, callback) {
 messages = messages.Records;
 if (messages && messages.length > 0) {
   messages.forEach(function(message) {
       console.log(message);
       //...
```

I see that cloudwatch prints the "OK DONE" message. However, SQS puts messages 'in flight' (and it stays in flight forever). My understanding is that once a successful response is sent, the message will be automatically deleted. My visibility timer = 10 min

Comment: Have you [deleted the message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-getting-started.html#step-receive-delete-message)?  SQS doesn't automatically delete the message for you.

Comment: Lambda is supposed to auto delete after a successful response is my understanding

Comment: Lambda does what your code tells it to do.  I've never heard of it doing anything like that.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html . Lambda polls the queue and invokes your function synchronously with an event that contains queue messages. Lambda reads messages in batches and invokes your function once for each batch. When your function successfully processes a batch, Lambda deletes its messages from the queue.

Comment: Well, I've learned something today - thank you.  Since Lambda is event driven and SQS is polling driven I hadn't used them together.  It looks like your code does something similar to [the node.js example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-create-package.html#with-sqs-example-deployment-pkg-nodejs) other than it only processes one message.  Do you not want to process everything available?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. I do look at all messages, but it is in the handleSQSMessages function which I did not post (event.Record is processed there)

Comment: I see a `forEach` in the AWS examples.  Your link says that if you don't respond to the batch (i.e. all the messages that your are given) then it does not delete the messages.  Are you reading everything given?

Comment: You should either set the Batch Size to 1 or loop over all events in the batch, not just the first element.

Comment: I have added a snippet of code from handleSQSMessages to show that I do loop over all the records in the event

Comment: Have you configured your SQS queue to serve as an event source for your Lambda function? If no, your lambda has to delete the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing some closing parenthesis/curly braces.
Is the handler callback being called in the handleSQSMessages callback? It's hard to tell with the missing braces - but if not, that's probably the reason it's failing.

Comment: I posted a snippet. The code runs fine. I store the data in aurora, which is exactly what I intend. However, the messages do not get deleted from SQS though the callback is invoked

Answer (score 0):

You could set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop` to `false` to send the callback response immediately, instead of waiting for all event loop tasks to get completed.